# Powershell Get-Content -> Parameter "-replace"

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

**Hi!**

- Is the **"-replace" Parameter** bounded to the **cmdlet "Get-Content"**? through googling i found it in many different contexts
- Why is the **-replace Parameter** not shown in the official Documentation? [Get-Content Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2)

## Issue:

The text apporaches like this:

> olor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
> LoremIpsum-648648sdfsd

I want to replace the substring via Regex from "LoremIpsum-xxx" to "Loremipsum"

This is my first Try:

```
(Get-Content "C:\File.cmd") -replace "[regex]::matches("LoremIpsum-(.*?)")" | Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\File.cmd
```

Comment: It's not a parameter for `Get-Content` it's actually a comparison operator [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-regular-expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) is not a `Get-Content` parameter, it is an  operator that allows to use a regular expression to find a specified pattern and then either remove or replace the matched text with another.

In your case, you can use

```
(Get-Content "C:\File.cmd") -replace '(?<=\bLoremIpsum)-\w+' | Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\File.cmd
```

The `(?<=\bLoremIpsum)-\w+` regex matches a hyphen (`-`) and one or more word chars (`\w+`) that are immediately preceded with a `LoremIpsum` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary).

*Note* you may replace `\w+` with `\S+` if you want to remove any one or more non-whitespace chars after `LoremIpsum`.

Alternatively, you can use

```
(Get-Content "C:\File.cmd") -replace '\b(LoremIpsum)-\w+', '$1' | Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\File.cmd
```

Here, `LoremIpsum` is captured into a capturing group (with ID 1 since it is the first capturing group in the regex), and the replacement is now `$1`, the replacement backreference referring to Group 1 value.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/efeu0E/1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/efeu0E/2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir - Why cant i simply google with keywords "powershell","-replace" and get the satisfying results? how do i approach a satisfying google search? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @NoErrorNoCry I used `powershell replace regex documentation` and the top result brought me to the necessary page.

Comment: @NoErrorNoCry By placing "-" in front of a keyword, it actually excludes this keyword from search! If you want to search for it literally, surround it in double quotation marks. Try this: `powershell "-replace"`

Comment: Got another problem: Sometimes the "-"-Hyphen emerges a few times:
`LoremIpsum-648648sdfsd-skldfjsdo54-545dfd6-sldfj` the pattern '(?<=\bLoremIpsum)-\w+' produces following output: `LoremIpsum-skldfjsdo54-545dfd6-sldfj` but i want to remove everything

Comment: Thanks for the tip with "By placing "-" in front of a keyword, it actually excludes this keyword f.." this one is actually gold .. top

Comment: @NoErrorNoCry No problem, see my "*Note you may replace `\w+` with `\S+` if you want to remove any one or more non-whitespace chars after LoremIpsum.*" Use `-replace '(?<=\bLoremIpsum)-\S+'`. Right, `-` excludes a word from search in Google search, hence, I did not use `-` before `replace` in my Google search.